# Upper bound on a vector norm

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, s.t $\|a\|_p<\varepsilon, \forall a\in A$. Can we have an upper bound on $\|a-a'\|_p$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\|a-a^\prime\|_p \le \|a\|_p + \|a^\prime\|_p\le 2\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

Think about this geometrically, somehow all these $a$'s lie in a ball with radius $\varepsilon$(under the $p$-norm). Then of course the maximum distance any of these points can be apart is $2\varepsilon$.